# java JTABLE - Refresh TextFields after Delete An item from database

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, refresh

I have text fields and a JTable on a Frame. When user clicks on the JTable row or moves key up and down, textfields filled up with these selected row values so that user can update the row. So the problem is when I select the row and then pressed the delete button the table refreshes but the textfields still show the deleted row values.So at this moment I dont want to reset the fields. I want to show the row values which comes before the deleted row in the text field

For example there are two rows

```
id  name  
1   hello
2   bello
```

user selected the row which has `ID` 2 and delete it. now the values on the textfield should be hello not bellow

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will involve less guess work and produce better response

Comment: *"Hope you understand my question."*  Hope you understand what a question is.  So far you've not asked a question, you've merely outlined a requirement or goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ListSelectionListener` on your `JTable` which sets the text of the `JTextField` elements based on the current selection in your `JTable`. When the delete button is pressed, you can have the `ActionListener` remove the selected row from the `JTable` and force the next selection in the model via [`setRowSelectionInterval`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29). Below is a simple example:

[image: Row Deletion Animation]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JTableDelete extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JTableDelete frame = new JTableDelete();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public JTableDelete() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] { { "Red" }, { "Green" }, { "Blue" }, { "Violet" }, { "Orange" }, },
                new String[] { "Colors" }));

        ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
                if (selectedRow != -1 && selectedColumn != -1)
                    textField.setText((String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumn));
                else
                    textField.setText("");
            }

        });

        contentPane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int rowCount = table.getRowCount() - 1; // -1 because counting starts at 0
                if (row != -1) {
                    ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row);
                    rowCount--; // 1 less row now
                    if (row < table.getRowCount()) // next selection
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                    else if (rowCount != -1) // end selection
                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(rowCount, rowCount);
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnDelete, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setEnabled(false);
        contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        pack();
    }

}
```